# Closing a GitLab Issue while on a different branch

Tags: gitlab, commit, issue-tracking

I can close issues from the main branch, but if I'm on the 'dev' branch or another branch, the issues don't get closed. In the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#closing-issues-automatically), it says that closing commit issues can only be done on the master branch. Is there a way to do it? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you answered your own question. Per the documentation, automatic closing of issues only applies when commits are added to the default branch of the project.

While there is no feature for this provided by GitLab, you can implement this yourself as an alternative. For example, if you are using GitLab CI, you could develop your own CI job that uses the [issues API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html) to find and close issues. However, you will need to implement the applicable logic yourself.